# Create a fillable PDF form with Office 2013 without Adobe?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013

Is there a way to create a fillable PDF form using Microsoft Office without using the Adobe Pro?

It appers for 2007 and 2010 version it was only possible to create locked Word documents or not fillable PDF. Now I'm wondering whether 2013 did change anything on that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it with only Word 2013, you need additional software to create the PDF form fields after the PDF has been created. Both Adobe Acrobat and InDesign do this. It is possible other, lower cost software also does it but I'm afraid I don't know.

Comment: I was afraid to hear this. Well... LibreOffice seems to do the job, so moving.

Comment: Useful to know that, thanks for the info. I generally keep a copy of Open office around for when MS Office fails me :) used it to good effect in the past when Word has corrupted very large files as it has a tendency to do. OOO has often been able to recover them when Word couldn't